# SQL Index Handling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an instance which having 25 large databases.

I have set a rebuild_all_indexes job to rebuild all indexes on every database.

Due to database large size and OLTP environment this job takes about more than 3,4 days to its completion.

Can any one help me out to handle this situation?

As job step I used some store procedures calling like this:

```
exec database1.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
GO
--exec database2.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
GO
exec database3.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
GO
exec database4.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
GO
exec database5.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
GO
exec database6.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
GO
exec database7.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
GO
exec database8.dbo.SP_JOBS_REBUILD_DB_INDEXES
go
...............
...............
upto database25.dbo.sp_jobs_rebuild_db_indexes
```

Comment: Why would you want to rebuild all of the indexes in all of the databases?  What problem are you having that rebuilding the indexes is required or solves the issue?

Comment: You will get a better response on the databases administrators site on stack exchange.

Comment: Sir as i mentioned i have OLTP environment and for reporting, performance & analysis i need to rebuild indexes at once in a week.

Comment: *If* you truly have to rebuild all indexes often (and I'm definitely not sure that's needed) - then don't do them in one job and not in one go. Analyse your situation and set up maintenance plans to run on data when it fits best into usage. It would be much better to only rebuild what is needed when it's needed.

Comment: Large size and OLTP does not mean you need to rebuild index. Have you actually measured any significant difference before and after rebuild? How much index fragmentation do you before rebuild?

Comment: Actually i have a production DB (main DB) and then its replication on 4 different servers for reason and this issue i'm facing on one of replication instance ... and for syn all dbs & fragmentation i need to rebuild all indexes on all databases once in a week. which help me to get storage and better performance.

Comment: ""Allan S. Hansen """ i think your advise will help me out.... i have to break down this single rebuild_index job into 3,4 no of jobs based on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience you should check the fragmentation of all index and rebuild or reorganize indexes according to their percentage of fragmentation. I recommande you to do this operation every nights. On my biggest sql server (more then 1 Terabytes) this operation take 2:40 every nights. Be careful to don't run this operation during databe backup.

This link can help you http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/12/sql-server-fragmentation-detect-fragmentation-and-eliminate-fragmentation/ there is a script to check fragmentation of indexes. As you can see it's recommended to perform a "Reorganize" between 5 to 30 % of fragmenation and perform a "Rebuild" when it's upper to 30%.

Personally I use a job with custom scripts, here are these steps :

- Retrieve index information from all database into a table (using
  select .. FROM   sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL,
  NULL, 'LIMITED') ps
- Based on the previous table, check percentage of fragmentation and
  execute a rebuild or reorganize

All are in only one job